# MsBuild Compile and build dependencies in parallel

Tags: c++, msbuild

I am working on a large C++ solution with lots of projects.

Some of those are build bottlenecks where dlls depend on a another that takes forever to build.

I have plenty of CPUs to build, but I can't get MSBuild to compile (not link) everything in parallel and only use dependencies at link time.

I essentially want to have on every project:

```
# build objects
msbuild /t:BuildCompile project.vcxproj

# only now build/wait for dependencies
msbuild /t:ResolveReferences;BuildLink project.vcxproj
```

I want the above to work as part of a single build (cascade to dependent projects).

I have been trying to mess around with MSBuild target build orders:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildSteps>
    SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables;
    SetUserMacroEnvironmentVariables;
    PrepareForBuild;
    InitializeBuildStatus;
    BuildGenerateSources;
    BuildCompile;

    ResolveReferences;

    BuildLink;
  </BuildSteps>
</PropertyGroup>
```

does not work, Resolve Dependencies in this setup does not build dependent projects.

Any ideas? Only the linker actually depends on referenced projects, the objs do not.

Comment: Have you tried [/maxcpucount or /m option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx)

Comment: *to compile everything in parallel* what do you mean with *everything*? Anyway with default options (being multi-processor compilation turned on, i.e. /MP switch for compiler) and by passing /m to msbuild, msbuild completely maxes out CPU here and runs like 20 cl processes at the same time. I don't think it will get any better than that.

Comment: @Troopers Yes, I have tried /m, this will make it compile the dependencies in paralle, but compiling the cpps in the current project will wait until all depenedncies have been compiled.

Comment: @stijn I want to have MSBuild compile the cpps of the current project at the same time as dependencies are being compiled, but wait with linking until all dependent projects are done (i.e. libs are available for linking).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution: first gets a list of all projects by 'parsing' them from the solution file. Not needed if you have that list already. Then invokes msbuild for all projects twice, once with the `BuildCompile` target, then with the `Build` target. I specifically chose the Build target (which will skip compilation since that is done already) as I am not sure your proposed solution of calling just ResolveReferences and Link targets will make a successful build in all cases, for example it might skip resource compilation, skip custom build steps etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AllTargets Include="BuildCompile;Build" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="mysolution.sln">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Solution" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <ItemGroup>
     <AllProjects Include="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match('%(Solution.Identity)', ', &quot;(.*\.vcxproj)&quot;').Groups[ 1 ].Value)"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild BuildInParallel="true" Projects="@(AllProjects)"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)"
             Targets="%(AllTargets.Identity)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Invoke like

```
msbuild mybuild.proj /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=Win32
```

I'm curious to see if this will improve your build times.

*edit* since you are seeing what look likes full rebuilds, maybe the BuildCompile targets only works properly when the other targets from BuildSteps ran as well. You could try splitting the build explicitely:

```
<MSBuild BuildInParallel="true" Projects="@(AllProjects)"
         Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)"
         Targets="SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables;
                  SetUserMacroEnvironmentVariables;
                  PrepareForBuild;
                  InitializeBuildStatus;
                  BuildGenerateSources;
                  BuildCompile;"/>

<MSBuild BuildInParallel="true" Projects="@(AllProjects)"
         Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)"
         Targets="Build"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this goes into the right direction. For some bizzarre reason though it is rebuilding all cpps during the "Build" step.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't do that unless they are not built, I also don't have the problem here. See edit.